# How do I make text text when you hover the mouse over it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, my friend asked me to make him a website for his YouTube channel. He wanted to have 4 links to other pages. These pages are: Home, About Me, Merchandise, and Contact (Just so he can have like, duo sessions or like guests and stuff). So here's what he said: "I want it so that when someone points at those pages before they click on it, I want the text to change in to a different color. Just like at terraria.org". So I said i might not know how, but he begged me, so yeah. So does anyone know how to do that? preferably using only HTML and CSS? I'm no too great at JS. But if it's the only option, I'll take it. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you think of checking how it's done on terraria.org?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't quite put my finger on where it exactly was.

Comment: Because you didn't know it was called "hover"? That's a fair explanation -- I copied your friend's description *verbatim* into Google to see what would turn up, and indeed: `hover:` did not hover near the top results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS pseudo-class [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks man! Sorry for asking the stupidest question ever, but I'm new to HTML and coding man. Sorry again, and Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Erm, Like this?

```
<style>
    a:hover{colour:yellow}
</style>
<a href="http://something.com">my link"</a>
```

Not to be a dick but you need to learn how to search before you ask:

Google: "css hover link"

Comment: Age dosn't excuse ignorance, if you want to learn something Google. I was playing around with C# and mySQL to emulate Habbo Hotel at 13. Didn't know what I was doing but I didn't expect people to hand it on a platter.

Comment: Gee, I'm sorry. I'm not a gamer, and I was more of a book worm. I didn't have a reason to code until last week, when we started learning to code at school. So don't expect me to be all geeky in a week.

Comment: And i said i was 13 so you stop using foul language.